# Is it possible to apply an XSLT transform to a DOM element?

Tags: html, xslt

I have a webpage that has many user-generated elements that need to be "cleaned" and I'd like the cleanup to be expressed as an XSLT transform because it suits the purpose quite well.

Is there a way to apply an XSLT transform to part of a webpage? (And does the source element have to be checked by something akin to tagsoup first, to make sure it's well-formed?)

All the examples I find are about fetching an XML file and an XSL file, via Ajax, and running one against the other, but not taking a subset of the DOM and running an XSLT on it. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the context you want to do that in? Is the document ("web page") already loaded in a browser window? Some browsers expose an API to Javascript to apply XSLT to DOM nodes e.g. Mozilla introduced an API and other browsers like Opera have copied it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_the_mozilla_javascript_interface_to_xsl_transformations.

And of course there is Saxon-CE that runs inside the browser: http://www.saxonica.com/ce/doc/contents.html. That even allows you to apply XSLT 2.0 to DOM nodes.

Comment: The Mozilla API looks exactly like what I'm looking for, so many thanks. Do you know if there's a cross-browser solution? (I've heard about Saxon CE but it's still very alpha, requires a lot of downloading, and will ask for a commercial licence when it's ready; I'd rather use in-browser XSLT 1.0 transforms that are more than enough for what I need).

Comment: As for a cross-browser approach, as I said Opera supports the Mozilla API as well, I think Chrome and Safari on the surface do too but I think you will run into problems when you execute it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985048/transforming-html-nodes-with-xslt-in-chrome-webkit). IE does not support that API and even with IE 9 that supports XHTML and SVG DOM documents I don't think you can apply XSLT to them as the DOM that IE implements is completely separated from the DOM that MSXML, Microsoft's COM based XSLT processor implements respectively consumes as XSLT input trees.

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML is not XML, I don't think you will be able to perform an XSLT transform on an HTML page. However, you will be able to do it on an XHTML page.